# Oracle Sql Query : How Pivot Function Sum() in Packages?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, sum, pivot

I use Oracle 10g and I query in Packages. How Pivot function sum() in Packages?

Sql Query.

```
WITH DATA_JOIN AS
 (SELECT S.START_DATE_GMT,
         S.NO_OF_CALL,
         S.RATE,
         T.TAX_RATE,
         T.EFF_DATE,
         T.EXP_DATE,
         S.COMPANY_CODE,
         T.COMPANY_CODE CC,
         S.SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID,
         S.event_type_id,
         S.PMN_ORIGIN,
         S.PMN_ROUTE
    FROM IR_V_ISM_RATE_BY_TRANS S
    LEFT JOIN IR_PMN_TAX T
      ON S.COMPANY_CODE = T.COMPANY_CODE
     AND S.PMN_ROUTE = T.PMN_CODE
   WHERE T.TAX_TYPE = '01'
     AND S.START_DATE_GMT <= T.EFF_DATE
     AND S.START_DATE_GMT >= T.EXP_DATE
      OR T.EXP_DATE IS NULL
   ORDER BY COMPANY_CODE),
TEMP_A AS
 (SELECT START_DATE_GMT,
         SUM(NO_OF_CALL) AS TOTAL_TRANSACTION,
         ((SUM(NO_OF_CALL)) * RATE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
         ((((SUM(NO_OF_CALL)) * RATE) * TAX_RATE) / 100) AS TOTAL_VAT,
         RATE
    FROM DATA_JOIN
   WHERE COMPANY_CODE = 'RIT' 
     AND SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID = '2'
     AND PMN_ROUTE = 'C2' 
     AND EVENT_TYPE_ID = '01'
     AND TO_CHAR(START_DATE_GMT, 'MM/YYYY') <= '01/2015'
     AND (TO_CHAR(START_DATE_GMT, 'MM/YYYY') >= '01/2015' OR START_DATE_GMT IS NULL) 
   GROUP BY START_DATE_GMT, SUB_EVENT_TYPE_ID, RATE, TAX_RATE
   ORDER BY START_DATE_GMT)

/* Result */
 SELECT 
 SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)AS EXCLUDE_VAT,
 SUM(TOTAL_VAT) AS SUM_VAT,
 SUM(SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)+SUM(TOTAL_VAT)) AS TOTAL_INCLUDE
FROM TEMP_A
GROUP BY TOTAL_AMOUNT,TOTAL_VAT;
```

Result SQL Query

```
EXCLUDE_VAT | SUM_VAT | TOTAL_INCLUDE
5.50        | 0.30    | 5.80
```

**I need Result Pivot**

```
Calculate Vat   | Total Amount
----------------------------------
EXCLUDE_VAT     | 5.50
SUM_VAT         | 0.30
TOTAL_INCLUDE   | 5.80
```

How Pivot Function Sum() in Packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpivot, not pivot, but 10g doesn't support either natively. There are ways to do it, [as shown here with decode](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php#unpivot), but in this case since you already have CTEs you could just union three queries against those instead:

```
/* Result */
SELECT 'EXCLUDE_VAT' AS CALCULATE_VAT,
  SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM TEMP_A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL_VAT', SUM(TOTAL_VAT)
FROM TEMP_A
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL_INCLUDE', SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)+SUM(TOTAL_VAT)
FROM TEMP_A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Oracle db right now, however I remember there being limits to using PIVOT with WITH statements. I could be wrong on that.

```
select * from (
    select 1 AS CV_ORDER,
       'EXCLUDE_VAT' as CALCULATE_VAT,
       SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
    from TEMP_A group by 1, 'EXCLUDE_VAT'
    union all
    select 2 as CV_ORDER,
        'SUM_VAT' as CALCULATE_VAT,
         SUM(TOTAL_VAT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
     from TEMP_A group by 2, 'SUM_VAT'
    union all
    select 3 as CV_ORDER,
        'TOTAL_INCLUDE' as CALCULATE_VAT,
        SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT) + SUM)(TOTAL_VAT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT
        from TEMP_A group by 3, 'TOTAL_INCLUDE'
    ) order by CV_ORDER
```